# Overriding JQGrid params defind in server side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm working on the CSS of a table which is generated via JQGrid in the server-side using C#. I tried to override the layout definitions (e.g width) in the client side (of course after the server-side table is generated in the code) but got nothing. the only thing that worked is creating a whole new jqgrid object, which obviously nullifies all server-side definitions, so it's no use.

Is there a way to somehow regenerate a JavaScript copy of the object in the client-side, and then apply changes to it?

Your kind assistance is most welcome.

edit:
here is to code used to generate the table with C#:

```
        this.projectGrid = new JQGrid
        {
            Columns = new List<JQGridColumn>()
            {
                new JQGridColumn { Visible=true,
                                   Editable=false,
                                 //  Width=70,
                                   DataField="compliance_colour",
                                   HeaderText="Comp.",
                                   Searchable=false,
                                    Formatter = new CustomFormatter
                                                             {
                                                              FormatFunction = "formatCmpImage"

                                                             }


                },
                new JQGridColumn{ DataField="ProjectID",
                                  PrimaryKey=true,
                                  Visible=true,
                                  Editable=false,
                                  HeaderText="ID",
                                //  Width=50,
                                  Searchable=false
                },
                new JQGridColumn{ DataField="OpsRegion",
                                  Visible=true,
                                  Editable=false,
                                  HeaderText="Ops Region",
                               //   Width=180,
                                  Searchable=false

                },
                  new JQGridColumn{DataField="customer",
                                 Visible=true,
                                 Editable=false,
                                 HeaderText="Customer Name",
                               //  Width=180,
                                 Searchable=false

                },
                  new JQGridColumn{ DataField="projectName",
                                  Visible=true,
                                  Editable=false,
                                  HeaderText="Project Name",
                                //  Width=300,
                                  Searchable=false,
                                  Formatter = new CustomFormatter
                                                             {
                                                              FormatFunction = "formatLink",

                                                             }


                },

                new JQGridColumn{DataField="projectManager",
                                 Visible=true,
                                 Editable=false,
                                 HeaderText="Project Manager",
                              //   Width=110,
                                    Searchable=false
                },
                new JQGridColumn{DataField="status",
                                 Visible=true,
                                 Editable=false,
                                 HeaderText="Status",
                              //   Width=70,
                                 Searchable=false

                },
                new JQGridColumn {DataField="type",
                                  Visible=true,
                                  Editable=false,
                                  HeaderText="Type",
                             //     Width=70,
                                  Searchable=false

                },
                new JQGridColumn {DataField="favorite",
                                  Visible=true,
                                  Editable=false,
                                  HeaderText="Favorite",
                              //    Width=60,
                                  Searchable=false,
                                  Formatter = new CustomFormatter
                                                                {
                                                                    FormatFunction = "formatFvImage",
                                                                    UnFormatFunction = "unformatCell"
                                                                }

                },
                 new JQGridColumn {DataField="compliance_reason",
                                  Visible=false      
                },
                 new JQGridColumn {DataField="lastUpdate",
                                  Visible=true,
                                  Editable=false,
                               //   Width=60,
                                  HeaderText="Last Update",
                                  Searchable=false,
                                  Formatter = new CustomFormatter
                                                                {
                                                                    FormatFunction = "formatReportLink",
                                                                    UnFormatFunction = "unformatCell"
                                                                }

                },
            },
           Width = Unit.Pixel(1400),
            ShrinkToFit=true,
            Height = Unit.Pixel(520),

        };
```

Comment: Do you use *free* open source [jqGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid/info) from [trirand.com](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) or some *commercial* product based on jqGrid like jqSuite from [trirand.net](http://www.trirand.net/licensing.aspx)? In the last case you should use another tag of the question like [jqgrid-asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change `width` of grid you can use [setGridWidth](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method. To overwrite many other jqGrid options you can use `setGridParam` instead. You can use the methods *after* the grid is created. In general you should use jqGrid [methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) if someone exist for exact the option (like `setCaption`, `setGridHeight`, `setColProp`, ...). If you find no special jqGrid method to change the options you should probably use `setGridParam` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I obviously tried this b4 posting my question. IMHO, The problem lies in the fact that the table is generated on the server-side, and thus a JS copy of this table obj must be first obtained, b4 trying to manipulate any params

Comment: @Matanya: You don't describe *how* (in which way) you "generate" the table (??? the grid or you use `tableToGrid`?). You should post more details. How you tried to change the options of jqGrid? Do you did it *after* the grid is created (see my answer)? If your JavaScript code will be called *before* the grid are created you can change *default* options of jqGrid on the page (`$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {...});`). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2678731/315935) for example.

Comment: @Matanya: The code which you posted in the **edit** part of the question shows that you use *commercial* product like jqSuite from [trirand.net](http://www.trirand.net/licensing.aspx) instead of [jqGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid/info). I can only repeat the suggestion from my last comment. You can find an example of such approach in UPDATED part of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10980350/315935) (the answer is not accepted, but I tested the code which I posted before and it works). Depend on where you included `<asp:Content>...` on the ASPX page you can reduce the code.