# How to send key-value string as additional postData?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Thanks to [Manuel van Rijn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612800/jquery-jqgrid-postdata-overriding-default-values) I got to know that we can send additional data like this:

```
 serializeGridData: function(postData) {
      var newPostData = $.extend(postData, {
        extraParam: 'EXTRA-PARAM-VALUE'
      });
      // newPostData now is (_search=false&nd=1324619663709&rows=100&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&extraParam=EXTRA-PARAM-VALUE)
      return $.param(newPostData);
    }
```

But how can I send a ready string containing params in format like "&Action=Count&param1=1&param2=2" ?

I tried to send such string straight as a variable:

```
serializeGridData: function(postData) {
                var newPostData = $.extend(postData, MyReadyStringParams);
                return $.param(newPostData);
            }
```

But as a result a got such wrong request:

```
http://www.domain.com/bigset.php?0=%26&1=S&2=F&3=_&4=R&5=o&6=o&7=m&8=s&9=1&10=%3D&11=t&12=r&13=u&14=e&_search=false&nd=1392540671755&rows=100&page=1&sidx=id&sord=asc
```

What I need to do to create valid request like:
    http://www.domain.com/bigset.php?_search=false&nd=1392540671755&rows=100&page=1&sidx=id&sord=asc&Action=Count&param1=1&param2=2
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
serializeGridData: function(postData) {
    return $.param(postData) + MyReadyStringParams;
}
```